# How are these two pointers different from each other?

Tags: c, function, pointers, integer

I'm new to C language and pointers in general. So my understanding of these two things is  basic.

I've been trying to create a structure that hold pointers to functions, nothing fancy. While doing so; I noticed that this statement:

`int *func()`
doesn't work. while this one actually works:

`int (*func)()`

What's the difference between them?  Is it because the first statement is only a pointer to integer. while the other pointer, *somehow*, points to a function? How so?

Comment: A function declared with `()` takes an unspecified number and type(s) of arguments. It's an obsolescent form that probably shouldn't be used in new code. If  your function takes no arguments, use `(void)`, not `()`. (C++ uses `()` to denote no arguments, but C++ is a different language.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int *func(void)
```

Defines a function named `func` that has no parameters and returns a pointer to an integer

```
int(*func)(void)
```

Defines a pointer to a function that has no parameters and returns an integer

The reason for this difference is *operator precedence*. Parerenteses have a higher precendence than `*`. Therefore in the first expression `int *func()` the function-parenthesis have the highest precedence and are considered first, so associate with the symbol `func` so the compiler knows that `func` is a symbol for a function. Therefore the rest is the return.

In the second instance `int(*func)()` there is an extra set of parenthesis. Inside the first parenthesis we see `*func`. As the parenthesis is the highest precendence (left-to-right) the compiler must interpret the contents of this set... `*func` is a pointer. OK a pointer to what? Look right and we see `()` so it is a pointer to a function. Then look left to see the return type.

Hope this makes sense :) Also try [***How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations***](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations) on CodeProject.com. It talks about something called the "Right-left rule", which is "...a simple rule that allows you to interpret any declaration...". It's a little more than half way down the page...

Also try [***cdecl: C gibberish ↔ English***](http://cdecl.org/). It's quite a nice implementation of the `cdecl` utility.

[image]

Comment: A function taking no arguments in C should really be declared as `(void)`, not just `()`.

Comment: +1. But cdecl.org does not require single-character identifiers. It's just some keywords (e.g. func, cast) which have to be avoided apparently. Also, I doubt the screenshot is needed.

Comment: ah ok thats what I ran into... assumed it was single letters

Comment: Suddenly everything makes sense. Thanks!